# Restrict Placeholder settings by Page Template

Tags: sxa, xm-cloud, sxa-jss

This is an XM Cloud with NextJS solution.

I am trying to set restriction by page templates in SXA. All pages share the same placeholders.

Creating the placeholder settings items under the tenant/presentation node works fine... but they are global.

I am trying to have a different set of component restriction by page type/template.

So far I have tried following this documentation

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/set-placeholder-restrictions.html

I created multiple partial design each with its own placeholder setting but it seems to always get the first placeholder item that it matches with the key and apply its restrictions globally.

Also tried setting the placeholder values in the standard values in the page template, but it only works if I place the full placeholder key path. ie : /headless-main/nameofplaceholder. Which I would not like to do because it will only work for that level. My containers can be nested, and I assume the nested containers inside a container will fall-back to the global placeholder setting.